# maximum key length in AppFabric?

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

Currently I am working on a ASP.NET MVC application.It is using AppFabric for Session and cache management.I am using API methods(put,get) to add and retrieve (key,value) pairs.I am having no of keys which are created based on number of conditions.i.e, Keys are variable in length.

What is the maximum length/size of a key in AppFabric?

Answer (score 0):

From [the AppFabric MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7ac975a-08c4-4f63-b99c-7033ae20dd63/what-is-the-max-size-of-a-cache-key-in-appfabric?forum=velocity):

> Q. What is the maximum length of the cache key?
>
> A. There is no limit on the key as such but it is subject to maximum
> message size. The maximum message size by default is 8 MB